# styling drop down/navigation bar actionbarsherlock font

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, styles, actionbarsherlock

In the application I have, I would like to have the `actionbar drop down's` font to be **white**. Till now I have the following style:

```
    <style name="Theme.MyApplications" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Title" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.SubTitle" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Solid" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.Title</item>
        <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.SubTitle</item>
    </style>
```

[image]

This style gives me a **black** colored font in `android 3.0 and higher`. Can someone please help me configure the font to be white ? 
The funny thing about this is that the action overflow popup's font appears in white.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for now I just used the simple

```
<style name="Theme.MyApplications" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

Its simple but it got the job done. And what got the job done was the change in the style's `parent`.

Answer (score 2):

You have apply the style to the native ActionBar as well:

```
    <style name="Theme.MyApplications" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Title" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.SubTitle" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Solid" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.Title</item>
        <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.SubTitle</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.Title</item>
        <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.SubTitle</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: says it requires API level 11 and more ... mine supports from 8 and above ... thats part of the reason why i got stuck.